# In JSF1.2 is it possible to redirect to a bean before a page is rendered?

Tags: jsp, jsf, redirect, javabeans

I know that in Seam, we could write an xml file (if my jsf page is named index.jsf -> index.page.xml) that we could add there

action execute="#{loginAction.checkIfBlaBla}"

so that JUST BEFORE the index.xhtml is rendered we could call a method of a Bean (Session or Managed, in seam it doesnt matter)

I am wondering if it is also possible in pure Java EE app coded with ejb3 and jsf v1.2?

In JSF2.0 it may be possible as it is more like Seam framework with the 2.0 version. But in 1.2 I am not sure, that's why I wanna ask to you all.

Any help would be appreciated,
Many thanks,
Baris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is JSF-own behaviour and the way has never changed since JSF 1.0, so yes, you should be able to do the same with JSF 1.2. If you have a more specific problem, feel free to ask a new question. For the time being, I'd suggest to get yourself through a basic JSF tutorial to pick up the trivials. The JSF tutorials at [Coreservlets.com](http://www.coreservlets.com/JSF-Tutorial/jsf1/) are very good.

Comment: I am back on working seam again for now, I couldn't practise my jsf example yet. When I begin it again, be sure I will ask so many questions:)
Many thanks

Comment: your answer suggests that the Seam-specific view preload mechanism (e.g. index.page.xml) described by Bariscan is part of the JSF spec.  Can you cite where in the spec this is mentioned?

Comment: @Michael: the question does not dictate some view-preload mechanism. I must however admit that the question is after all very ambiguous and that the terminology used by Bariscan is here and there misplaced/confusing.